# Tags for crashes and freezes

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a [freeze](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/freeze) tag, which I think I created, meaning cases when something is not responding. I think that's a useful tag because people use lots of different words to express this situation, so it's otherwise hard to search for.

(Note: I think it's not a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), because it has a valid, objective meaning. However, I can't see it be used alone — there should be an application or OS tag alongside.)

There's no similar general tag for crashes; do we not need one, or have we not recognized the need for one? Maybe it's enough to just have [kernel-panic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kernel-panic) and [segmentation-fault](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault). *(Side note: please make a synonym [segfault](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/segfault) → [segmentation-fault](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/segmentation-fault).)*

There's [error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error), with a [single question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9194/grub-error-15-no-boot-menu-nor-boot). That one seems too vague to me. Ban?

Comment: [error] has grown a bit (26 Qs now). I'd rather like to see it gone - way too generic to be useful. Not sure how to "bump" this with no bounty system here...

Answer (score 2):

I think "crash" is vague enough that it doesn't add much as a tag. Freeze is a little more specific.

I'm not particularly keen on [error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error), without qualifications. It's too early in the morning for me to be having *great* ideas, but what occurs to me is `grub-error` or `boot-error`.

Comment: I'd rather leave a question concerning grub error tagged merely as [tag:grub].

Comment: Outside of KP's ... I would consider `crash` a valid tag for a program that just die's for whatever reason.