# How should we re-delete the /crash and /error tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm late to the party, but it seems I'm not the only uninvited guest. The [error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) and [crash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crash) tags are still around, despite an apparent conclusion back in 2014 to burninate them:
[Error and crash tags, are they really useful?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2705/error-and-crash-tags-are-they-really-useful)

Do they need to be blacklisted?

Comment: We wouldn't be *re*-deleting them. They were never deleted.

Comment: Well, the conclusion wasn't really conclusive, as such. My answer only has 5 upvotes and one downvote. Doesn't really look like anybody cared. Gilles's now has one (mine). Let's see if anyone gets involved this time.

Answer (score 0):

There was no consensus that [crash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crash) needed to go. Out of the 300+ [error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) entries only the two that I could not burn are left, out of the others about 15 were changed (two had to be changed because [error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) was the only tag) and the rest deleted.